# Not able to run Shopizer shop (https://www.shopizer.com/) default implementation due to the following error

Tags: spring-boot, java-11, shopizer

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.<init>(DeserializationContext.java:211)

The following method did not exist:

    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.getReadCapabilities()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/JacksonFeatureSet;

The method's class, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/waseem.zawaideh/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.10.2/jackson-core-2.10.2.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser: file:/C:/Users/waseem.zawaideh/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.10.2/jackson-core-2.10.2.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
```

- I tried to change the related dependencies versions to make the same across the system, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please comment out Jackson dependencies

```
<!-- Jackson JSON Processor -->
<!--            <dependency>-->
<!--                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>${jackson-version-databind}</version>-->
<!--            </dependency>-->

<!--            <dependency>-->
<!--                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>${jackson-version}</version>-->
<!--            </dependency>-->

<!--            <dependency>-->
<!--                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>${jackson-version}</version>-->
<!--            </dependency>-->
```

Comment: It did not work